# What is the proper way to add delays to, eg. 74HCT151, verilog model so it is accurate to the datasheet?

Tags: verilog, delay, system-verilog

What is the proper way to add delays to this model of a 74hct151 - see below.
See also my effort at a solution.

I would like to see even one fully accurate (as possible) verilog model of 7400 timings so I could understand the concerns and build my own. The 74151 is interesting because the Y and _Y paths have different times and also because it's the most recent one I've needed for my homebrew"TTL" cpu.

I am using Icarus so I need a solution for that. I don't have other tools and I know that some tools have bugs/quirks/missing features so something that works on a commercial tool but not Icarus is an issue.

I am hoping someone would show me a solution so I can learn.

I do have a solution below but I think it's probably bit pants.

I want a design that allows through realistic glitches.but my earlier attempts suppressed short glitches due to how I was doing delays. I believe this is called "transport delay" as opposed to "inertial delay".

As mentioned in the following document using transport delays is useful for finding glitch risks.. section 4.3
[https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://cs.baylor.edu/~maurer/aida/desauto/chapter4.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjYtpS06pHsAhUEXRUIHVtJAos4FBAWMAB6BAgAEAE&usg=AOvVaw1CUNhobqxQe-pQIEZiBKm](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://cs.baylor.edu/%7Emaurer/aida/desauto/chapter4.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwjYtpS06pHsAhUEXRUIHVtJAos4FBAWMAB6BAgAEAE&usg=AOvVaw1CUNhobqxQe-pQIEZiBKm)_

With correct delays I am expecting to see a transition glitch on the Y/_Y during certain transitions due to the difference in the S and I propagation delay.

The data sheet says this chips glitches during transitions and this shows up in my best shot at the timings

```
These needed delays are taken from datasheet for HCT in ns
 I to  Y = 19
 I to _Y = 19
 S to  Y = 20
 S to _Y = 20
_E to  Y = 16
_E to _Y = 18
transition time Y, _Y = 7
```

See also https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74HC_HCT151_Q100.pdf

The basic code below has no delays.

How do I implement correctly?

See edaplayground link above for my novice solution.

I expect there is a more idiomatic way to get these timings.

Here is the basic logic without delays....

```
`timescale 1ns/1ns

module hct74151(_E, I, S, Y, _Y);
    output Y, _Y;
    input [2:0] S;
    input [7:0] I;
    input _E;

    wire o =
        (S==0 & I[0]) ||
        (S==1 & I[1]) ||
        (S==2 & I[2]) ||
        (S==3 & I[3]) ||
        (S==4 & I[4]) ||
        (S==5 & I[5]) ||
        (S==6 & I[6]) ||
        (S==7 & I[7]);

    assign Y = _E==0 ? o : 0;
    assign _Y = !Y;

    always @* begin
        $display("%9t %m ", $time, "_E=%1b  I=%8b  S=%1d   Y=%b _Y=%b ", _E, I, S, Y, _Y);
    end

endmodule
```

:

Comment: Are you looking for `specify` block?

Comment: I am using Icarus verilog btw. I don't believe this can be done with a specify block at least with Icarus.  I want all glitches to come thru, not suppressed. But it seems that the left hand side approach for delays works like a low pass filter so fluctuations on the input that are shorter than the propagation delay are suppressed. However I want a model that works like a real chip, a worst case with glitches galore.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, but is it idiomatic?
Is there a better way that works on ***icarus***?

```
module hct74151(_E, I, S, Y, _Y);
    parameter LOG=0;
    output Y, _Y;
    input [2:0] S;
    input [7:0] I;
    input _E;

    // setup timing be delaying the signals according to the data PD then combine them at last minute
    logic [7:0] Id;
    logic [2:0] Sd;

    always @*
        Id <= #(19) I;

    always @*
        Sd <= #(20) S;

    // according to nexperia _E->_Y is slower than _E->Y
    logic _Ed, Ed;
    always @*
        _Ed <= #(13) _E;
    always @*
        Ed <= #(18) ! _E;

    // combine
    wire O =
        (Sd==0 & Id[0]) ||
        (Sd==1 & Id[1]) ||
        (Sd==2 & Id[2]) ||
        (Sd==3 & Id[3]) ||
        (Sd==4 & Id[4]) ||
        (Sd==5 & Id[5]) ||
        (Sd==6 & Id[6]) ||
        (Sd==7 & Id[7]);

    assign Y = _Ed==0 ? O : 0;
    assign _Y = Ed==1 ? !O : 1;

    if (LOG) always @*
    begin
        $display("%9t %m ", $time, "_E=%1b  I=%8b  S=%1d   Y=%b _Y=%b (_Ed=%b, Ed=%b)", _E, I, S, Y, _Y, _Ed, Ed);
    end

endmodule
```

Comment: The Icarus bit is not relevant - it's just another V2K5 simulator. Having said that, my own experience of using `specify` is that it's handled subtly differently by different simulators, so I don't use it, and I agree that you should manually code your model. See https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Simulation-and-Verification/xvlog-xsim-bug/td-p/1155719 for an example of my own manual coding, with an inertial delay, and other stuff you should consider.

Comment: And you don't want 'all glitches to come through' - that's not how real silicon works. The real device may or may not glitch, depending on the technology and the timing, but the datasheet is just covering itself: you should assume a glitch, but not be surprised if it doesn't happen.

Comment: Is letting all glitches thru a worst case though?  I would prefer to have the misery of making a glitch go away if it helped me understand the risk of a design before building. BTW this is for a simulation of a homebrew "TTL CPU" (actually CMOS) so it's helpful I think to consider worst case.    What is the shorted gkich HCT or HC would let thru? It definitely isn't going to be picoseconds (joke) but is it 1 or 2 or 5 ns? I'm guess that less than the rise time would perhaps be near the limit but any ideas?   I'm really trying to understand how to  build realistic models.

Comment: Btw my comments about Icarus were motivated by the fact that the various tools have quirks and bugs and unimplemented features. I only have free Icarus sadly.

Comment: Btw i reported a few issues on timing in Icarus and they seem pretty responsive so that's something. And I'm trying to add timing to the test suites of my TTL chips